# LEETCODE problem - Minimum Number of Operations to Move All Balls to Each Box

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm using two while loops for solving this problem.The code is working fine for the default case. The default test case is cleared. But when I submit the code, It's going into an infinite loop. I checked a lot but couldn't find any mistake. could someone tell me where am I making mistake?
Link of the problem (You can read the problem here)-> https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-number-of-operations-to-move-all-balls-to-each-box/

my code -

```
class Solution:
def minOperations(self, boxes: str) -> List[int]:
    i=0
    j=i+1
    answer=[]
    count=0
    while i < len(boxes):
        while j <=len(boxes)-1:
            if boxes[j]=="1" and abs(i-j)==1:
                count+=1
               
            elif boxes[j]=="1" and abs(i-j)!=1:
                count+=abs(i-j)
            else:
                pass
            j+=1
            if i==j:
                j+=1
        answer.append(count)
        i=i+1
        j=0  
        count=0
    return answer
```

Test cases:

> Input: boxes = "110"
>
> Output: [1,1,3]

> Input: boxes = "001011"
>
> Output: [11,8,5,4,3,4]

Comment: Imagine you had a broom and you started to sweep from the left to the right. At each step keep track of the number of balls in the broom and the "accumulated moves" required to sweep the broom one box to the right. Then start again from the right and sweep to the left.

Comment: Thanks for this example .

Answer (score 1):

Your code is okay and there is no infinite loop. It is not optimal so you are exceeding the time limit for the question. Remove a few unnecessary `if` statements and it barely passes the acceptance threshold.

```
def minOperations(self, boxes: str) -> List[int]:
    i=0
    j=i+1
    answer=[]
    count=0
    while i < len(boxes):
        while j <=len(boxes)-1:
            if boxes[j]=="1":
                count+=abs(i-j)
            j+=1
        answer.append(count)
        i=i+1
        j=0  
        count=0
    return answer
```

Keep in mind this is not optimized at all. You can solve the problem in O(n)